# ¿Cómo hago para insertar una lista dentro de una lista?

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos

Hola necesito saber como hago para hacer que dos listas se unan es decir si tengo una lista1[1,3,5,7] y una lista2[2,4,6] necesito hacer que la lista1 se inserte en la lista2 de manera ordenada haciendo que esta lista2 quede [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] en un método dentro de la clase Lista. Hasta el momento lo único que tengo son los métodos normales que estamos usando como InsertarInicio, InsertarFinal, EliminarInicio, EliminaFinal y Mostrar.
El lenguaje en el que estoy es Java como IDE estoy usando Netbeans.
A continuación dejaré el código de la clase Lista que es en donde tengo todos los métodos

Clase Lista

```
public class Lista {
    private Nodo inicio;
    private Nodo ultimo;
    private int tamanio;

    public Lista() {
        this.inicio = null;
        this.ultimo = null;
        this.tamanio = 0;
    }
    
    public boolean Vacio(){
        return inicio == null && ultimo == null;
    }
    
    public void InsertarInicio(Object info) {
        if (Vacio()) {
            inicio = ultimo = new Nodo(info);
        } else {
            inicio = new Nodo(info, inicio, null);
            inicio.getSiguiente().setAnterior(inicio);
        }
        tamanio++;
    }

    public void InsetarFinal(Object info) {
        if (Vacio()) {
            inicio = ultimo = new Nodo(info);
        } else {
            ultimo = new Nodo(info, null, ultimo);
            ultimo.getAnterior().setSiguiente(ultimo);
        }
        tamanio++;
    }

    public void EliminarInicio() {
        if (!Vacio()) {
            if (inicio == ultimo) {
                inicio = ultimo = null;
            } else {
                inicio = inicio.getSiguiente();
                inicio.setAnterior(null);
            }
            tamanio--;
        }
    }

    public void EliminarUltimo() {
        if (!Vacio()) {
            if (inicio == ultimo) {
                inicio = ultimo = null;
            } else {
                ultimo = ultimo.getAnterior();
                ultimo.setSiguiente(null);
            }
            tamanio--;
        }
    }
    /*
    En el metodo Concatenar es donde tengo que hacer la concatenacion de las dos listas
    No hay nada porque me la paso haciendo y borrando ya que no me funciona lo que he realizado
    */
    public void Concatenar(){
        if (!Vacio()) {
            
        }
    }
    
    public String Mostrar(){
        String lista = "";
        Nodo aux = inicio;
        if (!Vacio()) {
            while (aux != null) {
                lista += aux.getInfo() + " ";
                aux = aux.getSiguiente();
            }
        }else{
            lista = "No hay datos";
        }
        return lista;
    }

    public Nodo getInicio() {
        return inicio;
    }

    public void setInicio(Nodo inicio) {
        this.inicio = inicio;
    }

    public Nodo getUltimo() {
        return ultimo;
    }

    public void setUltimo(Nodo ultimo) {
        this.ultimo = ultimo;
    }

    public int getTamanio() {
        return tamanio;
    }

    public void setTamanio(int tamanio) {
        this.tamanio = tamanio;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pon lo que has hecho hasta ahora para poderte ayudar

Comment: Hola Japv ya actualicé mi pregunta y coloqué todo el código que tengo de la clase Lista, Si necesitas la clase Nodo me avisas para volver a actualizar y perdón la tardanza pero me enfoque en intentar hacer eso y no revise la pagina hasta ahora

Answer (score 0):

En particular que lenguaje estas utilizando? Algunos lenguajes permiten realizar ese comportamiento mediante funciones predefinidas.

Si ésta pregunta está relacionada al concepto lógico de como se debería estructurar una función realizada en pseudo-código, te respondo lo siguiente:

En primer lugar vas a necesitar tener acceso a los punteros que organizan los nodos de la lista. Dentro de la clase "Lista" debería existir una función que devuelva el puntero al  nodo N de la lista (es decir que es posible que sea una función recursiva que camine de nodo en nodo hasta llegar al número N). Luego en la clase nodo deberá existir una función privada que permitan actualizar los punteros de la clase.

Lo primero que deberás hacer es acceder al primer nodo, preguntar si el valor del mismo (suponiendo que en la lista se almacenen int, como sugiere el ejemplo dado) es mayor o menor al valor del primer nodo de la segunda lista (la que queremos insertar en la primera).

Un ejemplo podría ser:

`if (Lista1.getNode(index).getValue() < Lista2.getNode(index).getValue()){`

`Lista1.addNodeAfter(index, Lista2.getNode(index));`

`}`

`index++;`

Donde `getNode(index)` es la función que accede al nodo index de la lista, la función `getValue()` retorna el atributo 'Value' de la clase Nodo y donde `addNodeAfter` modifica los punteros del nodo index para que apunte hacia el nuevo nodo que se agrega.

Si tu lista estuviera doblemente enlazada deberías modificar los nodos de index y index+1.

Espero que esto responda mas o menos tu pregunta. Cualquier cosa chifla!

Comment: Estas ofreciendo apurado una respuesta elaborada, porque no sabes que lenguaje usa, muchos usuarios hacen preguntas y despues no responden mas.